# Azure DevOps - Git pipeline with windowsfilecopy is copying the full directory

Tags: git, azure, devops, pipeline

I've had this issue with both Git and TFVC on DevOps. I've established a pipeline that copies the git (or tfvc) directory to what is our test server, which is a local/physical windows server with iis running a coldfusion instance. The server is in the agent pool and the files are updating with WindowsFileCopy. The problem is that, even if I only change one file, it does this step "checkout test@main to s" which copies the whole directory to a folder in the C: drive (C:\agent_work\1\s), then from there it copies the whole directory to the target one ( c:\inetpub\wwwroot\intranet ). It will also sometimes create a new folder (_work\2, _work\3, and so on), so it adds to the HD. The whole process, even if I've only updated a single file, takes 3 minutes or more. So, can I somehow change my yml to only include an altered file, or at least to skip the step of copying it to _work?

```
trigger:
  - main

pool:
  name: 'Default'  # Replace with the name of your agent pool
  demands:
  - agent.os -equals Windows_NT  # Optional: Ensure it runs on Windows-based agents

steps:

  - task: WindowsMachineFileCopy@2
    inputs:
      SourcePath: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)'
      MachineNames: 'PR1-TEST'
      AdminUserName: 'ntdomain\admin_user'
      AdminPassword: '$(admin_password)'
      TargetPath: 'c:\inetpub\wwwroot\intranet'
```

[image: Current process]

Answer (score 1):

By default Azure devops doesn't have this option but you can achieve this by
disabling the get source which you can achieve by

```
- checkout: none
```

Then add a cmd or powershell task and use git sparse checkout. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout

Now get the parts of your repository using api. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/items/get-items-batch?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1&tabs=HTTP

Comment: I notices the last step of the file copy is `C:\agent\_work\3\s to c:\inetpub\wwwroot\intranet` - Can I just change the agent to checkout directly to my working directory?

Comment: I believe every time when you do checkout, In the backend the code works like clean and checkout. So, directory should not play any role. Although its worth giving a shot.